# Bounding the integral of the derivative of the absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am struggling with the following question: Let's consider a function $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, that is, a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that its weak derivative belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Now, I would like to bound the following integral: $$
\int_0^x\vert f'(y)\vert dy.
$$
I am looking for some bound in terms of $c\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R})}$. In some sense, some part of me would like to get rid of the absolute value so I can compute directly $$
\int_0^xf'(y)dy=f(x)-f(0),
$$
which is trivially bounded thanks to Sobolev's embedding, but of course this ""trick"" is not true.

Does someone have any hint to do it? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think there is any such a bound. We can find infinitely differentiable functions $f_n$ with compact support such that $\|f_n\|_{\infty}$ is bounded but $\int |f_n'|$ is not.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if $f$ is infinitely differentiable (smooth) with compact support, then $\int \vert f'\vert$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean that $\int |f_n'| \to 0$ as $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a bound in term of $\|f\|_\infty$ doesn't exist.

Indeed, consider the sequence $f_n\in H^1(\Bbb R)$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(nx) &; x\in [0,2\pi] \\
0 &; x\notin [0,2\pi].\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, we have $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$.

Now, suppose (for contradiction) that such a bound exist, i.e. we can find $C>0$ such that 
$$
\int_0^x |f'(t)| dt < C\|f\|_\infty,
$$
then we must have 
$$\begin{align}
4n &= \int_0^{2\pi} |n\cos(nt)| dt \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} |f_n'(t)| dt \\
&< C\|f_n\|_\infty \\
&= C
\end{align}$$
for any $n\in\Bbb N$. This is a contradiction, hence we cannot find a bound in term of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm.